# Redux-persist sync problem on closing window or user logout

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

Hello everybody i am trying to connect redux, redux-persist, redux-state-sync

So far it was good until i was testing. Problem is when 2 user logged in (fp,sp);

1. fp: creates an entity
2. sp: log out
3. fp: deletes the created entity
4. sp: after login in created entity still in localStorage so sp sees
   an entity that doesnt exist.

Here is the the my code
Store.tsx

```
import { AnyAction, applyMiddleware, createStore, Reducer } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk, { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import { createStateSyncMiddleware } from 'redux-state-sync';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  whitelist: [
    //some reducer names
  ],
};

const config = {
  blacklist: ['persist/PERSIST', 'persist/REHYDRATE']
};

const persistedReducer: Reducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer as any);

export const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware<DispatchFunctionType, StateType>(thunk, createStateSyncMiddleware(config)))
);

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

type DispatchFunctionType = ThunkDispatch<StateType, undefined, AnyAction>

type StateType = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

index.tsx

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {persistor, store} from '@store'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import {  initMessageListener } from 'redux-state-sync';
//codes
initMessageListener(store);
        ReactDOM.render(
          <Provider store={store}>
             <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <App />
            </PersistGate>
          </Provider>
          , rootElement,
        )
//more codes
```

Is there any way clean localStorage before run persistor ? Or any idea how to fix the problem